# Add an outline to the currently hovered element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I  would like all elements with the class "hoverOutline" to have an outline when you hover over them. This CSS works *mostly* fine:

```
.hoverOutline :hover {
    outline: 2px solid black;
}
```

Only problem is this causes any parent elements with that class to have an outline as well. I understand that this is intended (as you *are* hovering over them too), but I would like to only outline the innermost child.(the one that would trigger an event first onclick).

I would like to add that I have looked into this, and most people use JQuery or some hacky work-around in pure CSS. For me, Javascript is 100% okay.

EDIT: This is for a bookmarklet, so I can't know in advance what elements will be on the page. This must work for ALL elements with that class, but that don't have  a child with that class..

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't seem to fix the problem. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `.hoverOutline:hover` try removing the space between the 2 words

Comment: remove the class from the parent elements

Comment: Andy Ray how could that be done with JS? (or CSS but as far as my research goes that isn't possible). I can't figure out how to detect if an element has a child with that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Demo 2 uses JavaScript to isolate and outline elements that meet two requirements:

1. Must have the `.hover` class
2. Must not have any descendants with the class `.hover`

**Note:** The `<legend>` has `.hover` class as well (actually everything has `.hover`), so as it fulfills the requirements, it too has the hover effects.

---

If the post you have submitted has no typos then the problem is pretty simple. A pseudo-class like `:hover` has a specific syntax in that it suffixes the targeted selector like so:

```
.hoverOutline:hover {
    outline: 2px solid black;
}
```

To address the parent having the same class and you need to exclude the parent, try using the parent's tagName like so:

```
.hoverOutline:hover {
  outline: 2px solid black;
}

section.hoverOutline:hover {
  outline: 0 none transparent;
}
```

In these 2 rulesets the second one is applied to the parent by specifying it's a `<section>` and placing it after the original ruleset which is more general and lower in [specificity](https://specificity.keegan.st/).

### Demo 1

```css
.hoverOutline :hover {
  outline: 2px solid black;
}

.hover:hover {
  outline: 2px solid black;
}

fieldset.hover:hover{
  outline:0 none transparent;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Incorrectly Syntax</legend>
  <button class='hoverOutline'>HOVER</button>
  <button class='hoverOutline'>HOVER</button>
  <button class='hoverOutline'>HOVER</button>
  <button class='hoverOutline'>HOVER</button>
  <button class='hov'>hover</button>
  <button class='hoverOutline'>HOVER</button>
  <button class='hoverOutline'>HOVER</button>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class='hover'>
  <legend>Correct Syntax</legend>
  <button class='hover'>HOVER</button>
  <button class='hover'>HOVER</button>
  <button class='hover'>HOVER</button>
  <button class='hover'>HOVER</button>
  <button class='hov'>hover</button>
  <button class='hover'>HOVER</button>
  <button class='hover'>HOVER</button>
</fieldset>
```

### Demo 2

```js
window.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseEnter, false);

window.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseLeave, false);

function mouseEnter(e) {
  /* if hovered node is NOT the registered
  || event listener...
  */
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    // Reference hovered element
    var tgt = e.target;

    // Reference the first child with .hover
    var kid = tgt.querySelector('.hover');

    /* if hovered node has class .hover and
    || does NOT have a child with class .hover...
    */
    if (tgt.classList.contains('hover') && !kid) {

      // add class .outline to hovered node
      tgt.classList.add('outline');

      // Otherwise do nothing and end function
    } else {
      return;
    }

    // Stop the bubbling phase
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}

function mouseLeave(e) {

  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    var tgt = e.target;
    tgt.classList.remove('outline');
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
form {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.outline {
  outline: 3px solid red
}
```

```html
<form id='form' class='hover'>
  <fieldset class='hover'>
    <legend class='hover'>Correct Syntax</legend>
    <button class='hover'>HOVER</button>
    <button class='hover'>HOVER</button>
    <button class='hover'>HOVER</button>
    <button class='hover'>HOVER</button>
    <button class='hov'>hover</button>
    <button class='hover'>HOVER</button>
    <button class='hover'>HOVER</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: This works, but not when the legend or fieldset also have the "hover" class. If they did, they would also get an outline when hovering over the buttons. That's what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: @IsaacChen See updated answer, sir. No jQuery/JavaScript involved just CSS

Comment: I added an edit to the post. This is for a bookmarklet, so I do not know in advance/have access to the HTML. All I am doing is applying that class to every element that your cursor is hovering over, and what I need to do now is only outline the innermost element. @DhavalPankhaniya gave a good JQuery answer, but if there is a way to do it with vanilla JS that would be a big help.

Comment: @IsaacChen update with Demo 2 with JavaScript ready for review.

Comment: This is perfect! And exactly what I asked for, vanilla JS. You earned this accept :)

Comment: Great, happy coding, sir.

Answer (score 3):

> [*The element Selector*](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp)  are used to "find" (or select) HTML elements based on their element name, id, class, attribute, and more.

that mean you can have the same class but define the tag with that class to handle see examlpe

```css
a.hoverOutline:hover {
    outline: 2px solid black;
}
a {
 width:220px;
 height:50px;
 display:inline-block;
 background-color:blue;
 color:white;
 line-height:50px;
 text-align:center;
 margin:auto;
}
div.hoverOutline{
 width:420px;
 height:100px;
 display:inline-block;
 background-color:green;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverOutline"><a class="hoverOutline"> This a tag mast outline on hover</a></div>
```

Comment: I've just added an edit saying that I don't already know the contents of the page. This is for a bookmarklet, so I can't hardcode the different elements.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
$(".hoverClass1").hover(function(){
    $(".hoverClass2").removeClass("hoverClass2");
    $(this).addClass("hoverClass2");
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hoverClass2");
});
```

```css
.hoverClass:hover{
    border:1px solid red
}

.hoverClass1{
}

.hoverClass2{
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hoverClass1">
    <input type="text" class="hoverClass1" placeholder="hover me !!">
</div>
```

Comment: Will this work even if that input is the child of a div with that class? Like, only the input would get an outline even if there is a parent with the same class?

Comment: @IsaacChen can you please check now ? did you mean this ?

Comment: This perfectly highlights my problem. This works as I would like, until you hover over the input. When you do, both the input AND the div get an outline. I would like only the input to get an outline. (and if the input had a child, hovering over that would give THAT an outline, but the input would no longer have one. Hope that makes sense

Comment: I really wanted to avoid JQuery, but it seems it's the only way. I'll have to embrace it :). Thanks for the answer!